# why does ssis transfer object stage return smo failure

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to copy a database using SSIS Transfer SQL Server Objects Task.

```
[Transfer SQL Server Objects Task] Error: Execution failed with the following error: "An exception occurred in SMO.".
[Transfer SQL Server Objects Task] Error: Execution failed with the following error: "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: server".
```

I hit test connection and prove that I have the right server name and password.  [image]

Comment: I dont get this error. Are you using any parameters in your settings? Remeber to mark CopyAllObjects as true. However, your better of use SSDT to copy/merge Databases and compare schemas. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

Comment: no.  not at this package.  all passwords/names are filled in at the connection.

Comment: And I'm not trying to copy ALL objects, just tables and data.

Comment: Why on earth would you copy data like this? Doesnt make sense. Script it instead though SQL much easier

Comment: ok.  never done that before.  got an example?

Answer (score 3):

My guess is bug was introduced with 2017 version of SSDT. To fix you need to down level the project from 2017 to 2016 using these steps:

1. right click on the name of your project in the "Solution Explorer".
2. go to the "properties" menu
3. in the opened window titled "Deployment Property Pages", within the left-hand menu, drill down the "Configuration Properties" to the "General" attribute
4. you'll see a tab titled "Deployment Target Version" on the right pane on the menu, there - choose "SQL Server 2016"
5. click "OK" and agree to all later refactoring request and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that if I am running the package locally from Visual Studio (VS), then I get the same error.
My workaround is:

1. Setup the SMO connection server as `<my-server-name>` in VS
2. Deploy it to the server from VS
3. Test-run it from the server itself (find the package in Integration Services Catalog > SSISDB, right-click and select 'Execute...')

`<my-server-name>` is the name of your server, could also be '`localhost`'

For some reason VS does not get the server name, although I inserted it in the SMO connection. But running the package on the server itself, seems to have worked.